# AWS RDS: Running db dumps in to the server really slow

Tags: mysql, aws

I am migrating data from out servers to AWS (from MySQL to Aurora) and inesrting the data is terribly slow. Is there a way to speed things up?

Right now I'm creating gzipped dump files on our server (these take anywhere from a megabyte to a few hundred megabytes) and taking the dump + zipping it takes for example 22 seconds. Transferring that dump takes 2 seconds. But then extracting the data and inserting it at AWS end takes 208 seconds. For these smaller (~2MB zipped) databases the problem isn't that big, but the times grow exponentially. If the dumping and gzipping takes 216 seconds, transmitting takes 20 seconds then extract+running dump in takes 5200 seconds..

Any advice on how to get around this bottleneck would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your dumps using [extended inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_extended-insert)? You might want to remove secondary indexes from the table definition before importing the data and recreate them later, that way they are not being modified all the time but built more efficiently once.

Comment: Yes, the dumps are using extended inserts and majority of them don't have secondary indexes. When running these inserts locally to my own database the insert times are a mere fraction of what it takes in Amazon's end.

Comment: In that case I would check configuration (and differences to your local server). And read http://hashmysql.org/wiki/InnoDB_Import_Speed for some tricks.

Comment: How much RAM?  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`